# Not receiving push notification when the app is in the foreground

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, push

I  have an App using  Mobile V8 and Cordova MFP-push plugin. Currently , I get notifications when the app is in the background. However, I am not getting any notification when the app is open/foreground.

Can you give some suggestion on how to debug this issue .

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symptoms are consistent with a case of no callback to handle the notification.

For example:

You have defined `MFPPush.registerNotificationsCallback(notificationReceived);`

but not

```
var notificationReceived = function(message) {
   alert(JSON.stringify(message));
};
```

Please refer the following link:

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/handling-push-notifications/cordova/

Comment: Thanks Vivin, I have the callback function define . but I will validate it again

Comment: Do, I still need to save the last message receive when  the app is in background. So, when the user open the app  they see the message as a popup

Comment: The push notifications that are received when application is in the background or not running, is queued by the SDK. When the application comes to foreground ( by tapping the notification in the notification center), the queued messages are automatically passed to the callback. This is taken care.